# vue-i18n, alternative for this.$i18n using the composition api?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-i18n

trying to implement vue-i18n in a component with composition api.
I want to be able to set some translation messages inside of the onMounted hook. In the options api, I would use `this.$i18n.setLocaleMessage(locale,  messages)`.

However, `this` is unavailable within the composition apis Setup() method. So it gives me undefined when I try the above. I can do it by importing i18n into the component:
`import { useI18n } from 'vue-i18n'` and then make an instance of it `var i18n = useI18n({}), i18n.setLocaleMessage()`, but I would rather prefer the one line solution like the first one.

Answer (score 13):

Just use `t` from `useI18n` as follows :

```js
const {t} = useI18n({})
//then use in any place in the setup hook
onMounted(()=>console.log(t('someWord'))
```

Comment: For my case, I also needed to add the **legacy: false** option when creating the VueI18n instance.
Example :

`// 2. Create i18n instance with options

const i18n = VueI18n.createI18n({

  legacy: false, // you must set `false`, to use Composition API

  locale: 'en', // set locale

  fallbackLocale: 'en', // set fallback locale

  // ...

})

// ...`

I saw this from that link: https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/guide/advanced/composition.html

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem using the @vue/composition-api package with Vue 2. This setup requires vue-i18n v8.x, which doesn't have the useI18n composable.

I found luck creating a composable with my own useI18n function, modeled after this one from the creators of vue-i18n: https://github.com/intlify/vue-i18n-composable/blob/master/src/index.ts

Their solution is in TypeScript, so here's a translated JavaScript version in case it's useful for you:

```
/**
 * Adapted from https://github.com/intlify/vue-i18n-composable/tree/master/src
 * This is temporary to allow us to use VueI18n 8.x with the Composition API and Vue 2
 * Once we upgrade to Vue 3 (which allows an upgrade to VueI18n 9.x), we can remove this
 * in favor of VueI18n's useI18n() hook
 */

import { computed, getCurrentInstance } from '@vue/composition-api'
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n'

let i18nInstance = VueI18n

export function createI18n(options) {
  i18nInstance = new VueI18n(options)

  return i18nInstance
}

export function useI18n() {
  if (!i18nInstance) throw new Error('vue-i18n not initialized')

  const i18n = i18nInstance

  const instance = getCurrentInstance()
  const vm = instance?.proxy || instance || new Vue({})

  const locale = computed({
    get() {
      return i18n.locale
    },
    set(v) {
      i18n.locale = v
    }
  })

  return {
    locale,
    t: vm.$t.bind(vm),
    tc: vm.$tc.bind(vm),
    d: vm.$d.bind(vm),
    te: vm.$te.bind(vm),
    n: vm.$n.bind(vm)
  }
}
```

I saved that in `src/composables/useI18n.js` and use it in a Single File Component like so:

```
<template>
  <h1>{{ t('translate-me') }}</h1>
</template>


<script>
import { useI18n } from '@/composables/useI18n'

const i18n = {
  messages: {
    en: {
      : 'Finish Arranging Widgets',
    }
  }
}

export default {
  i18n,

  setup() {
    const { t } = useI18n()

    return { t }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

On nuxt 2 bridge:

```html
<script setup lang="ts">

const { $i18n } = useNuxtApp()
$i18n.t('key')

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To expand upon Orvis Evans' answer, if you are using Nuxt 2 with @nuxtjs/composition-api and Typescript you can try using this composable

```ts
// composables/useI18n.ts

/**
 * Adapted from https://github.com/intlify/vue-i18n-composable/tree/master/src
 * This is temporary to allow us to use VueI18n 8.x with the Composition API and Vue 2
 * Once we upgrade to Vue 3 (which allows an upgrade to VueI18n 9.x), we can remove this
 * in favor of VueI18n's useI18n() hook
 */

import {
    WritableComputedRef,
    computed,
    getCurrentInstance,
} from '@nuxtjs/composition-api'
import Vue, { VueConstructor } from 'vue'
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n'

export interface Composer {
    locale: WritableComputedRef<string>
    t: typeof VueI18n.prototype.t
    tc: typeof VueI18n.prototype.tc
    te: typeof VueI18n.prototype.te
    d: typeof VueI18n.prototype.d
    n: typeof VueI18n.prototype.n
}

export function useI18n(): Composer {
    const instance: any = getCurrentInstance()
    const vm =
        instance?.proxy ||
        (instance as unknown as InstanceType<VueConstructor>) ||
        new Vue({})

    const i18n = vm.$i18n

    if (!i18n) throw new Error('vue-i18n not initialized')

    const locale = computed({
        get() {
            return i18n.locale
        },
        set(v: string) {
            i18n.locale = v
        },
    })

    return {
        locale,
        t: vm.$t.bind(vm),
        tc: vm.$tc.bind(vm),
        d: vm.$d.bind(vm),
        te: vm.$te.bind(vm),
        n: vm.$n.bind(vm),
    }
}
```

use it in a Single File Component like so

```html
<template>
  <h1>{{ t('translate-me') }}</h1>
</template>

<script>
import { useI18n } from '@/composables/useI18n'

const i18n = {
  messages: {
    en: {
      'translate-me': 'It\'s working!',
    }
  }
}

export default {
  i18n,

  setup() {
    const { t } = useI18n()

    return { t }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to import **useI18n** and define below as a const before using it.

```
import { useI18n } from "vue-i18n";

const {t} = useI18n({})
```

Comment: It only works if i18n config includes [`legacy: false`](https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/guide/advanced/composition.html#basic-usage).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me using Vue3 composition API.

Configuration
`main.js`

```
import { createI18n } from "vue-i18n";

const i18n = createI18n({
legacy: false,
locale: "en",
.....
```

In my component `App.vue`

```
<script setup>
import { useI18n } from "vue-i18n";
const { t } = useI18n();

onMounted(() => {
t('common.success')
....
```

Lastly, my translation file `locales/eng.json`

```
{
    "common": {
      "success": 'Succesfull'
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If people checking this for a **nuxt 3** project using `@nuxtjs/i18n` module and not being able to access the `usei18n()` composable outside of a setup component error message, you can use the following code:

```
const nuxtApp = useNuxtApp()
const i18n = nuxtApp.$i18n as Composer
```

and then be able to use `i18n.t(<your-key>)` as usual within your composable

Comment: Do you have a link to some documentation for that?

Comment: sadly can't remember from where I picked that up :/ Remember being struggling with it though

Answer (score 0):

I have a composable that needs access to VueI18n. With Vue 2 I would simply pass `this.$i18n` on. With Vue 3, I thought it would be easier thanks to `useI18n()`. As you know, that is not the case. However, passing on `this.$i18n` also does not do the trick anymore. Instead, I do this inside the setup() function / setup block.

Given I have a composable like this:

```js
export default function myComposable (i18n: ReturnType<typeof useI18n>) {
  // ...
}
```

I can pass the i18n object on, like this:

```js
const i18n = useI18n()
myComposable(i18n as ReturnType<typeof useI18n>)
```

This seems to work and satisfy TypeScript. However, you do need to cast the parameter to the return type. I haven't figured out why or whether there is a cleaner solution.